# Asp.net MVC 4 dynamic server and client side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

My company is developing a multitenancy application that has to be fully customizable through the database. This includes validation, so i created a couple of tables containing information about jquery validation methods and the way they are to be assigned to properties.

I have disabled automatic property validation generation, and marked each relevant property with an attribute that correctly generates multiple client side validation rules. However, the problem arises when i have to validate the model on the server side. I have implemented validations for required, digits and number, however i am not satisfied with that solution.

Is there a way to dynamically link my custom validation attribute with built in attributes? The general idea is that my custom validator would recieve a set of required validation methods from the database, and would propagate the validation check to the built in MVC validation method so I don't have to implement it.

Sorry for not posting the code, but I'm not allowed to do it. I would still appreciate a general guideline if this is doable in MVC.

Thank you

---

Update:

My attribute extends ValidationAttribute and IClientValidatable.

Client side validation is not a problem.  IClientValidatable returns an enumeration of ModelClientValidationRule that MVC flawlessly translates into proper jquery validation rules. Database stores jquery validation method names, such as 'digits', 'number', etc, along with method parameters.

My problem is with the "public override bool IsValid" method. I can get the list of jquery validations to perform, but i have to manually implement validation methods. Basically, I want to check the validation rule and if it equals 'required', I want MVC's RequiredAttribute validation to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

I did that before, create your own validation attribute that will depend on DB info to validate data , also create custom helper to render correct client side validation depending on that attribute value

Comment: So you know already what to do just create your ValidationAttribute inhirreted from Attributes and code it, or you need to be more spesific of what is stopping you